# Database query on rewrite

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I  have PHP script that runs every 5 mins and gets data from an API then writes it to a MySQL table. Users (300+) of my site can query that data via data-tables and other pages present some of that data.
The PHP script get API data then

```
foreach($array as $row)
{
    $query .= "INSERT INTO table_name 
    (
        col_name1, 
        col_name2, 
        col_name3, 
        col_name4, 
        col_name5
    ) 
    VALUES
    (
        '".$row["value1"]."', 
        '".$row["value2"]."', 
        '".$row["value3"]."', 
        '".$row["value4"]."', 
        '".$row["value5"]."'
    );";
}

mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM table_name");

mysqli_multi_query($connect, $query);
```

DELETE then INSERT into that empty table every time the script runs.
The table has 1000 rows and this will grow over time.
I am getting reports that the data-table is empty sometimes and they would have to refresh a few times before anything shows up.

Is there a better way of structuring the DB, tables and/or queries.

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! _Never_ trust outside data. This is not only a security issue, but if any value would contain a single `'`, your query will break.

Comment: We probably need a bit more information about the data: does the entire dataset change every time? Is it the case that 'events' remain fairly constant, but values change? Is there simply a churn of old data disappearing and new data appearing? Some samples would help.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a check to see if any data is received before deleting the data, that way if no data is read, at least the previous data would be in the table.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson and SloanThrasher, I should have said this process is very new to me and based on your replies it seem that there is a lot of things I need to consider, most of them i will have to research.

Comment: @Nick only the values changes... its basically the prices for products that changes but the structure stays the same I hope :)
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "name": "product_name", 
            "make": "product_make", 
            "price": "procuct_priceChange"
        },

Comment: Look at doing a REPLACE rather than DELETE/INSERT. Provided you have a pirimary key, your users will have a much better experience.

Answer (score 1):

Running individual insert statements for each row will be agonizingly slow.

It would be more efficient to run a multi-insert, inserting multiple rows with a single statement. For example, inserting four rows with a single statement.

```
INSERT INTO t (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?) ,(?,?,?) ,(?,?,?) ,(?,?,?)
```

One potential downside is if one the rows fails to insert due to an error, the whole statement is rolled back, and none of the rows are inserted.

The maximum length of the SQL statement is limited by `max_allowed_packet`. It's not necessary to insert all of the rows in a single statement. Inserting 10 rows at a pop would significantly reduce the number of statement executions.

Assuming the table uses the InnoDB storage engine...

If we disable auto-commit, and run the `DELETE` statement and the `INSERT` statements in the context of a *single* transaction, then the table wouldn't appear to be "empty" to other sessions. The other sessions would continue to see the contents of the table as it was prior to the `DELETE`... until the `COMMIT` is done.

---

The code pattern appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. (And particularly open to a lot of nastiness, using multi-query.

Best practice for mitigating SQL Injection is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

---

**EDIT**

As an alternative approach, if the table has a primary key or unique key, consider

loading a temporary table (not the target table).

Then run statements to apply the changes to bring the target table into sync with the temporary table. We'll refer to the temporary table by the name source.

-- update existing rows

```
 UPDATE target t 
   JOIN source s
     ON s.id = t.id
    SET t.col = s.col 
      , t.foo = s.foo
      , t.bar = s.bar
```

-- insert new rows

```
INSERT INTO target
SELECT s.*
  FROM ( SELECT r.*
           FROM source r
             -- anti-join 
           LEFT
           JOIN target q
             ON q.id = r.id 
          WHERE q.id IS NULL
        ) s
```

-- remove deleted rows

```
 DELETE t.*
   FROM target t
     -- anti-join
   LEFT
   JOIN source s
     ON s.id = t.id
  WHERE s.id IS NULL
```

This avoids having to "empty" the target table, so concurrent SELECT statements will still return rows while the target table is being "sync'd".

The DML UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE operations against the target table can be executed in the context of a single transaction.

Comment: Everything sounds great and it seems to be what I should be doing but unfortunately since I am still learning structure etc, I dont understand how its written.

Comment: or anyone can you write this another way I don't understand the shorthand.

Comment: Understand this: the code pattern in the original is vulnerable to SQL Injection, the code is broken. If we do a `DELETE` of all the rows in the table, and then a `COMMIT`, then a subsequent SELECT is going to see an empty table. So, if we do the `DELETE`, we don't have to do the `COMMIT`,  we can continue in the context of the same transaction, doing `INSERT` operations, and after thats done, we can do the `COMMIT`. But I think a better pattern is to load a staging table first, and then apply the changes from the staging table to the target table.

Comment: This answer addressed the question that was asked: "is there a better way?". Yes, there is. This answer gave several recommendations of patterns that  avoid excruciatingly slow RBAR (row by agonizing row) processing, and avoid having the table appear empty to other sessions. For performance, we think in terms of processing sets (relations)  instead of performing operations one row (tuple) at a time.